# Error after native facebook login - Must pass all fields to buffer - expected 5, saw 3

Tags: react-native

I'm having an issue with some of the native facebook login plugins out there namely - https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login and github.com/brentvatne/react-native-login

I'm getting the same error with both of the example projects, right after the login login flow returns from whichever login method is launched (native facebook, or if you don't have it installed - web login)

Instead of my app loading, its showing a loading screen for AwesomeProject then red screening to show: Must pass all fields to buffer - expected 5, saw 3. With no stack trace in the console etc.

I've had this same error in both the plugins, and I've tried the methods to resolve in this GitHub issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1606 **Note however**, that it runs perfectly fine when react-native bundle and running without the development env on the phone. Anyone else ran into this issue? I'm running react-native 7.1

Comment: Please edit your question to show the specific code you have tried.  Repositories tend to change over time and it's more code than is what is actually relevant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that running some of the Sample apps, namely AwesomeProject and using the same simulator when running my project, produced this error. I fixed it by resetting content and settings on the emulator from the drop down menu.